# JCL, JOB to run every night

Tags: dataset, batch-processing, jcl

So I have some JCL code that backs up a PDS for me whenever I submit the job. My question is if it's possible to create some JCL code that will backup my PDS, every night and automatically, and how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Most mainframe site's have a scheduling package (e.g. opc) that will run jobs / schedules at specific times, typically this is restricted to production jobs. Also many sites use HSM to automatically backup all dataset, often only 2 versions are kept though.

Comment: Your boss sends a memo to the Support Team's boss and they arrange it (by scheduling something, as Bruce has said).

Comment: If there is some difficulty with using site backups or HSM, you could write a rexx to copy the PDS, and invoke it when you login or logout. That way it is automatic but under your control. How the rexx is invoked is somewhat site-specific.

Answer (score -1):

Find out with automation or scheduling product they use.

Tivoli is quite popular.

So you could ask if your shop uses Tivoli Workload Scheduler (still referred to as OPC); or Tivoli Netview.

If you tell us will product they have you can they setup either a daily job using TWS or with Netview you can use the "TIMERS" command to fire off a command every similar to chron.

Comment: Ahh yes...it's been awhile since I've participated in Stackoverflow.  I forget all the nitty gritty, troll, and egos....err my bad.